# laravel - option all values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hi i would like to know how to create an "option" in a "select" that gets all the possible values of that "select". I have tried whereIn and whereBetwen, but cant get it. Someone even mentioned using Jquery for it. The laravel version is 5.4.

This is the code:

controller

```
function catalog(Request $abc) {
    $categoryesc = $abc->categoryesc;
    $manufaesc = $abc->manufaesc;
    $priceesc = $abc->priceesc;
    $modelesc = $abc->modelesc;
    if (empty($modelesc)) {

        $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', [$categoryesc])->where('Manufacturer_id', [$manufaesc])->where('Price', '<=', $priceesc)->get();
    }elseif (Auth::check()){
        $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Model', $modelesc)->first();
        $colours = DB::table('colours')->pluck('Colour', 'id'); 
    }
    else {
        return redirect('login');
    }
    return view('catalog', compact('robots', 'categories', 'colours')); 
}
```

blade file:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) }}
    {{ Form::select('categoryesc', ['0' => 'Any Category', '1' => 'Light', '2' => 'Medium', '3' => 'Heavy'], '0') }}
    {{ Form::select('manufaesc', ['0' => 'Any Make', '1' => 'Xenon', '2' => 'Tauron'], '0') }}
    {{ Form::select('priceesc', ['0' => 'Any Price', '100' => '100', '200' => '200'], '0') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Error:

```
ErrorException in 164eed4705c5997d268ffab821c82effa7651a2b.php line 31:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$Model (View: C:
(...)\resources\views\catalog.blade.php)

in 164eed4705c5997d268ffab821c82effa7651a2b.php line 31

at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in 
PhpEngine.php line 44

at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\(...) \\ storage\\ framework\\ views/ 
164eed4705c5997d268ffab821c82effa7651a2b.php', array('__env' => 
object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => 
object(ViewErrorBag), 'robots' => object(Builder))) in CompilerEngine.php 
line 59

at CompilerEngine->get('C:(...)\\resources\\views/catalog.blade.php', 
array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => 
object(ViewErrorBag), 'robots' => object(Builder))) in View.php line 137

at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
```

Comment: Not entirely sure of what your asking for, could you give an example or the results your getting and the ones you want?

Comment: @Nigel Ren example, when i select the "Any Category", i want to get all the values of the array, in this case the categories "Light", "Medium" and "Heavy".